# I would like to send commands and requests from a client side app to a Linux server

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, remote-management, protocols

So I am planning/designing an app running on Mac that will send commands and make data requests to a linux server. Some of the things I would need to do will be send file manipulation commands, zip files, send commands to a screen, and retrieve the output of a screen. Basically, it will be for administering a Minecraft server.

My question is, is there an endpoint or service in Linux I can use to trigger shell scripts to do this? How can I read a stream from the screen? If none of this exists, what language is best? What protocol? I'm most familiar with HTTP but that might not be ideal here.

Comment: What do you mean by "send commands to a screen"?

Comment: SSH / Xforwading on Linux and PuTTY / Xming on Windows? It gives you shell access on the client and the possibility to display remote X applications.

Comment: @bahamat my bad, forgot a tag, I mean the program called screen, I actually have seen how to do this in a minecraft backup script someone wrote, they are able to send minecraft commands to the screen exactly as if they were there typing it with a keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft is a Java game if I am not mistaken, so maybe Java will be a suitable tool. But I would recommend Python, especially the python's socket libraries.

Doug Hellmann has an exceptional [example at his site](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/SocketServer/) (Doug's the man with Python examples)

Python is installed by default with any modern OSX and quickly installable with any Linux distro.

Comment: Ah good call, I've learned a bit of Python on my own and never had a real good project in mind, this sounds like it might be it.

Comment: Take a peek at the tool for Python: iPython, will let you test your code interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a fun project. If your more familiar with HTTP protocols, I'd recommend [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC). Most popular languages will have a native XML-RPC binding, so slight-to-no issues developing on OS X & pushing to Linux production box. You'll still need to write an API to handle your exact requirements, but there's enough info & community support for XML-RPC to get started.

- [Javascript](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc)
- [Objective-C](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/XMLRPC/)
- [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html)
- [Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/index.html)